# Convert a bytea column to OID while retaining values

Tags: postgresql, types, casting, oid, bytea

I'm trying to alter a `bytea` column to have type `oid` and still retain the values.

I have tried using queries like:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN mycol_tmp oid;
UPDATE mytable SET mycol_tmp = CAST(mycol as oid);
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN mycol;
ALTER TABLE mytable RENAME mycol_tmp TO mycol;
```

But that just gives me the error:

```
ERROR: cannot cast type bytea to oid
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433041/understanding-cast-from-bytea-to-oid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A column of type Oid is just a reference to the binary contents which are actually stored in the system's **pg_largeobject** table. In terms of storage, an Oid a 4 byte integer.
On the other hand, a column of type bytea *is* the actual contents.

To transfer a bytea into a large object, a new large object should be created with the file-like API of large objects: lo_create() to get a new OID, then lo_open() in write mode, then writes with lo_write() or lowrite(), and then lo_close().

This can't reasonably be done with just a cast.

Basically, you would need to write a ~10 lines piece of code in the language of your choice (at least one that supports the large object API, including plpgsql) to do this conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do realize that an OID is very different from a bytea, but I figured there was some query you could use to put the contents of the bytea in to a oid reference. It will not be a big problem to use another language to do it though. Thanks again!

Comment: I was wrong about the lack of a server-side write function to write the data into the large object, I've edited the answer accordingly. It turns out it's called lowrite, (not lo_write) and it's not mentioned in the docs, but it certainly could be used for the copy step.

Answer (score 5):

Postgres **9.4** adds a [built-in function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/lo-funcs.html#LO-FUNCS-TABLE) for this:

```
lo_from_bytea(loid oid, string bytea)
```

From the [release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-9-4.html#AEN119691):

> - Add SQL functions to allow [large object reads/writes][12] at arbitrary offsets (Pavel Stehule)

For **older versions**, this is more efficient than what [has been posted before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16367919/939860):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION blob_write(bytea)
  RETURNS oid AS
$func$
DECLARE
   loid oid := lo_create(0);
   lfd   int := lo_open(loid, 131072);  -- = 2^17 = x2000
   -- symbolic constant defined in the header file libpq/libpq-fs.h
   -- #define   INV_WRITE   0x00020000
BEGIN
   PERFORM lowrite(lfd, $1);
   PERFORM lo_close(lfd);
   RETURN loid;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT;
```

The `STRICT` modifier is smarter than handling NULL manually.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1489f/1)

More in this related answer:

- [Understanding cast from bytea to oid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29433041/understanding-cast-from-bytea-to-oid/29435148#29435148)

Answer (score 4):

I think the best answer can be found at [Grace Batumbya's Blog](http://gbatumbya.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/create-a-large-object-lo-from-binary-data-bytea-on-server-side/), *in verbis*:

> The algorithm is pretty simple, get the binary data, if it is null, return null. Else create a large object and in the lowrite function, pass it the binary value, instead of a path to a file.
>
> The code for the procedure is below. Note that the lo_manage package should be installed for this to work.

```
create or replace function blob_write(lbytea bytea)
   returns oid
   volatile
   language plpgsql as
$f$
   declare
      loid oid;
      lfd integer;
      lsize integer;
begin
   if(lbytea is null) then
      return null;
   end if;

   loid := lo_create(0);
   lfd := lo_open(loid,131072);
   lsize := lowrite(lfd,lbytea);
   perform lo_close(lfd);
   return loid;
end;
$f$;
CREATE CAST (bytea AS oid) WITH FUNCTION blob_write(bytea) AS ASSIGNMENT;
```

> So now the following code works:
>       CREATE TABLE bytea_to_lo (
>          lo largeObj
>       );

```
INSERT INTO bytea_to_lo VALUES ( DECODE('00AB','hex'));
```

I've tried it and works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure its late, but for anybody having the same problem in future.

I also faced a similar issue where I had old data in the columns of text directly in the columns not as OIDs. And when I was trying to use that data with upgraded application I too was getting

I used the knowledge of this thread to solve this issue. I strongly feel that whoever stumbles upon this question would surely like to have a look at this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29484326/1229355)

Answer (score -1):

To solve the problem, I successfully used blob_write procedure from Grace Batumbya's Blog: http://gbatumbya.wordpress.com/2011/06/.

Comment: Please elaborate by at least quoting the most relevant bits. Link rot happens.