# Understanding cast from bytea to oid

Tags: sql, postgresql, types, casting, blob

I'm using `PostgreSQL 9.2`.
[This blog entry by Grace Batumbya](https://gbatumbya.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/create-a-large-object-lo-from-binary-data-bytea-on-server-side/) provides a cast from `bytea` to `oid`.

```
create or replace function blob_write(lbytea bytea)
   returns oid
   volatile
   language plpgsql as
$f$
   declare
      loid oid;
      lfd integer;
      lsize integer;
begin
   if(lbytea is null) then
      return null;
   end if;

   loid := lo_create(0);
   lfd := lo_open(loid,131072);
   lsize := lowrite(lfd,lbytea);
   perform lo_close(lfd);
   return loid;
end;
$f$;
CREATE CAST (bytea AS oid) WITH FUNCTION blob_write(bytea) AS ASSIGNMENT;

CREATE TABLE bytea_to_lo (
   largeObj lo 
);
```

I didn't understand why should we create `bytea_to_lo` table? How is it going to be used by `PostgreSQL`?

Comment: So you "found" that? Would you kindly link to the source?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Sure, I got that from [there](https://gbatumbya.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/create-a-large-object-lo-from-binary-data-bytea-on-server-side/).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139077/convert-a-bytea-column-to-oid-column-with-retained-values-postgresql

Comment: This is a pretty bad idea IMO, and should be written with an explicit function call instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast is not a true cast. It's just (ab)using the convenient syntax. A [large object (LO)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/largeobjects.html) is created in the background which is stored separately and the OID referencing it is returned.

[Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/lo-intro.html)

> All large objects are stored in a single system table named
>   `pg_largeobject`. Each large object also has an entry in the system
>   table `pg_largeobject_metadata`. Large objects can be created, modified,
>   and deleted using a read/write API that is similar to standard
>   operations on files.

The returned OID is basically a FK to the PK of the system table [`pg_largeobject`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-largeobject.html).

`CREATE TABLE` is completely independent from the function and pseudo-cast.

```
CREATE TABLE bytea_to_lo (
   largeObj lo 
);
```

It's just a typical use case for the assignment cast created above, which becomes apparent from the following line that you forgot to quote:

```
INSERT INTO bytea_to_lo VALUES (DECODE('00AB','hex'));
```

#### What happens here?

The data type `lo` is a domain over the base type `oid`, created by the additional module [**`lo`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/lo.html) (incorrectly referenced as "lo_manage package" in the [blog enty of Grace Batumbya](https://gbatumbya.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/create-a-large-object-lo-from-binary-data-bytea-on-server-side/)). [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/lo.html#AEN127441)

> The module also provides a data type `lo`, which is really just a domain
>   of the `oid` type. This is useful for differentiating database columns
>   that hold large object references from those that are OIDs of other things.

The function [`decode()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) returns `bytea`. The `INSERT` statement assigns the `bytea` value to the column `largeObj`, which triggers an assignment cast to its type `lo`, and that's where the above cast comes in.

### Warning / Corrective / Update

The blog entry is sloppy and outdated by now.

- Does not bother to mention that ([per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createcast.html)):

  > To be able to create a cast, you must own the source or the target
  >   data type and have `USAGE` privilege on the other type.

  Effectively, you must be superuser.
- Typo in `CREATE TABLE`: column name and type reversed.
- The function definition is verbose and inefficient. This would be better (for Postgres **9.3** or older):

  ```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION blob_write(bytea)
    RETURNS oid AS
  $func$
  DECLARE
     loid oid := lo_create(0);
     lfd  int := lo_open(loid,131072);  -- = 2^17 = x2000
     -- symbolic constant defined in the header file libpq/libpq-fs.h
     -- #define   INV_WRITE   0x00020000
  BEGIN
     PERFORM lowrite(lfd, $1);
     PERFORM lo_close(lfd);
     RETURN loid;
  END
  $func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT;
  ```

  [**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1489f/1)

There is a [**built-in function**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/lo-funcs.html#LO-FUNCS-TABLE) for this in Postgres **9.4**. Use that instead:

```
lo_from_bytea(loid oid, string bytea)
```

From the [release notes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/release-9-4.html#AEN119691):

> - Add SQL functions to allow [large object reads/writes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/lo-funcs.html) at arbitrary offsets (Pavel Stehule)

For `CREATE CAST` ([per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createcast.html)):

> The first argument type must be identical to or binary-coercible from the cast's source type.

I suggest an overloaded variant with only a `bytea` parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lo_from_bytea(bytea)
   RETURNS oid LANGUAGE sql AS
'SELECT lo_from_bytea(0, $1)';

CREATE CAST (bytea AS oid) WITH FUNCTION lo_from_bytea(bytea) AS ASSIGNMENT;
```

Since the pseudo-cast has quite a big side effect, I am not convinced to make that an `ASSIGNMENT` cast. I'd probably start with explicit-only:

- [Generate series of dates - using date type as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21045909/generate-series-of-dates-using-date-type-as-input/21051215#21051215)